# In Ruby how do I open a file and write each member of an array to a separate line and close it?

Tags: ruby

This is a class method.  So far this is what I have:

```
  def self.save(array, my_file)

    File.open(my_file) do |f|
        f.lines.each do |line|
            text_line = line
            text_line.write
        end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do as below:

```
def self.save(array, my_file)
  File.open(my_file,'w') do |f|
    f.puts array
  end
end
```

[`IO::puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-puts), if called with an **array argument**, writes each element on a new line. You don't need to close the file manually, as you called [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-open). As per the doc of `IO::open`, *if the optional code block is given, it will be passed io as an argument, and the IO object will automatically be closed when the block terminates.*

Answer (score 1):

Use File#puts which is inherited from [IO#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-puts)

```
def self.save(array, my_file)
  File.open(my_file, 'w+') do |f|
    array.each do |line|
      f.puts line
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it will be `f.puts line`, you missed it :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit it was obviously an oversight, and you could have being nicer with your comment

Comment: this will not work, as the file `my_file` was not opened for writing. Use `w` or `w+` in `File.open`